# Flutter: How can I listen for status bar tap in ios?

Tags: ios, swift, flutter, dart

I need to listen for a tap event on the status bar and call a custom function (call Scrollable.ensureVisible). However, there is no way I can find a way to do this.

As far as I understand, there are 2 options:

1. Listen to this event from flutter, but I haven't found any way to do this.
2. Write native code that will listen to the status bar tap event and use MethodChannel to deliver the event to dart.

All my attempts to implement both options failed. Could you please tell me how it can be done?

Comment: please pick a language

Comment: @pilchard what do you mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep in mind that Flutter has the ability to render every pixel of your screen. So, to override the default tap action on the status bar you have to add a `GestureDetector` where the status bar is normally positioned.

This can be achieved with a `Stack` where the first child is your main widget tree (usually a `Scaffold`) and the second child is a `Positioned` with the `GestureDetector`:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class StatusBarTapExample extends StatelessWidget {
  const StatusBarTapExample({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
      children: [
        Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text('Title'),
          ),
          body: Center(
            child: Text('Content'),
          ),
        ),
        // Status bar tap override
        Positioned(
          top: 0,
          left: 0,
          right: 0,
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).padding.top,
          child: GestureDetector(
            excludeFromSemantics: true,
            onTap: onStatusBarTap,
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }

  void onStatusBarTap() {
    print('onStatusBarTap');
  }
}
```